# SqlServer2016, Hibernate schema-validation: Missing table, but table exists in db

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I've got problem with schema validation on SqlServer 2016. Hibernate throws exception that table [ADDRESS] is missing. But I've added this table through script. My Address class has annotation

```
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
```

Creating script is:

```
CREATE TABLE [party_dictionary].[address] (
  [id] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [apartment_number] NVARCHAR(30),
  [city] NVARCHAR(255),
  [country] NVARCHAR(255),
  [house_number] NVARCHAR(30),
  [street] NVARCHAR(255),
  [zip_code] NVARCHAR(30),
  [created_by] NVARCHAR(255),
  [creation_timestamp] DATETIME,
  [modified_by] NVARCHAR(255),
  [modification_timestamp] DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY ([id])
)
GO
```

and so, I've tried changing table name in Address class to lower case, in sql to upper case, still same effect. I've tried run hibernate on create-drop, to have scripts, and they are the same as mine (without brackets). There is also annotatnion @ManyToOne in my other entity, which looks like this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "RESIDENCE_ADDRESS_ID")
private Address residenceAddress;
```

I've tried using @Transient, no effects.

Do you guys have any ideas?

**FULL STACK TRACE**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303) [catalina.jar:8.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:8.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753) [catalina.jar:8.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729) [catalina.jar:8.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976) [catalina.jar:8.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1853) [catalina.jar:8.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [ADDRESS]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

 18-Jan-2018 14:26:23.939 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/partydictionary]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1853)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:805)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [ADDRESS]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 34 more
```

**ADDRESS CLASS**

```
@Audited
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@AuditOverride(forClass = EntityLog.class)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Address extends EntityBase {

    @Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private ID id;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", updatable = false)
@CreatedBy
@Getter
protected String createdBy;

@Getter
@LastModifiedBy
@Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY")
protected String modifiedBy;

@Getter
@CreatedDate
@Column(name = "CREATION_TIMESTAMP", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", updatable = false)
protected LocalDateTime creationTimestamp;

@Getter
@LastModifiedDate
@Column(name = "MODIFICATION_TIMESTAMP", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
protected LocalDateTime modificationTimestamp;

@Column(name = "ZIP_CODE")
private String zipCode;

@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;

@Column(name = "STREET")
private String street;

@Column(name = "HOUSE_NUMBER")
private String houseNumber;

@Column(name = "APARTMENT_NUMBER")
private String apartmentNumber;

@Column(name = "COUNTRY")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Country country;
}
```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace? and the code for your `ADDRESS` class?

Comment: Where are you specifying that that table is in the party_dictionary schema?

Comment: in properties file, but as i wrote, hibernate makes same scripts, so it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server use the defaul dbo schema but you specified your own schema and you need to configure it. You can add this in you properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo
```

or in your case:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=party_dictionary
```

or you can specify it there:

```
@Table(name = "ADDRESS", schema="yourSchema")
```

Other thing is that hibernate is by default using the lowercase table name so if you want to keep the original name, you can add:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: thanks, I really don't remember how I solved the problem, because it was almost 2 years ago, but I think you're right.

Comment: Thanks! spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl does the trick in my case!

Comment: Bingo! This solved my problem. How did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Hi base on this post https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4217631, I think is not enough just declare the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema`, in the case of SQL Server is better to set the default database as it shows below:

[image]

It is highly recommended to create user per database and map the corresponding database schema.